# Finding the minimal polynomial of an element over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If I am finding the minimal polynomial of an element $\alpha$ over a field $F$, all I need to do is:

1. Find a (monic?) polynomial $f$ in $F[x]$ that vanishes at $\alpha$.
2. Show that $f$ is irreducible.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes...though it may prove to be tougher that what one could think at first sight.

Comment: If you mean of an element of a field $K$ over a field $F$, then yes. If $\alpha$ is in a $F$-algebra that is not integral, then $f$ need not be irreducible ; but it must have minimal degree.

Comment: Yes. Some people specify monic, some don't.